# Como puedo centrar una imagen dentro de un slider?

Tags: javascript, css, slider

he creado un slider el cual cambia automaticamente las imagenes, el problema es que no se como centrar las imagenes, he intentado de varias formas pero no logro centrarlas. Me han dicho que intente utilizando un margin: 0px auto; pero sigo sin conseguir centrarlas.
**HTML**

```
`<div id="slider">
            <div class="galeria">
                <div><img src="img/rojo.jpg" title="rojo"></div>
                <div><img src="img/International 2019.jpg" title="International"></div>
                <div><img src="img/graduacion.JPG" title="Graduacion"></div>
              </div>
        </div>`
```

**CSS**

```
 #sidebar{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    width: 31%;
    float: right;
}

#sidebar h4{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: black;
}

#sidebar img{
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar p{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport{
    height: 250px !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.galeria').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    stopAutoOnClick: true,
    pager: true,
    slideWidth: 900,
});
```

[image: Asi es como se ve la imagen, no se ve un buen trozo de ella]

Answer (score 2):

La imagen es un elemento de línea, por lo que además del margin: auto debes agregarle display: block al CSS.

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```